# Estimate Uncertainties in Rietveld Refinement

Tags: experimental-physics, crystals, error-analysis, data-analysis

I have the output of an x-ray diffraction experiment made on a thin film.
Here I report the output of the experiment (I analyzed those data using powdercell and coloured regions have been excluded because who performed that experiment said that those peaks are due to "misfunctioning of the diffractometer").
Here I report the output of that experiment:

[image]

Moreovrer the best Refinement (I defined "best" looking at R-values and visual inspection of match between original peaks and refined peaks) I got via PowdeCell is the following:

[image]

Here I report the results of the Rietveld refinement performed via PowderCell:

```
 Refinement of Pb1.X_Y    7/14/2015  3:13:08 PM
 ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯

 Si_struct_powcell  27.74 vol.%    (scf: 0.2560)
 Pb_struct_powcell  71.26 vol.%    (scf: 0.6577)
 SI3N4_alpha_man  1.00 vol.%    (scf: 0.0092)

 R-values       Rp=94.24   Rwp=453.16   Rexp=1.25
  8 iterations of 20


 parameter                     old             new

 Si_struct_powcell
 ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
 lattice         a :          5.4300         5.4238

 profile         U :          0.0000        -0.4742
 PsVoigt2        V :          0.0000         0.0967
                 W :          0.0050         0.0138

 overall B         :          0.0000              -



 Pb_struct_powcell
 ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
 lattice         a :          4.9508         4.9261

 profile         U :          0.0000        -0.0545
 PsVoigt2        V :          0.0000         0.1333
                 W :          0.0050        -0.0411

 overall B         :          0.0000              -



 SI3N4_alpha_man
 ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
 lattice         a :          7.7660         7.7123
                 c :          5.6150         5.5775

 profile         U :          0.0000        -0.1946
 PsVoigt2        V :          0.0000         0.0831
                 W :          0.0050         0.0321

 overall B         :          0.0000              -




 global parameters
 ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
 zero shift        :          0.0000        -0.0410

 displacement      :          0.0000              -

 backgr. polynom   :               3              3

 coeff.         a0 :          0.0000     -4119.9640
                a1 :               0          553.4
                a2 :               0         -14.83
                a3 :               0         0.1132
```

My question is: how can I compute an uncertainty on the new cell parameters? I looked around on the web but I have not found anything...

I read that R-values should be related with goodness of fit and so uncertainty on refined cell parameter but this is not ever the case...
Any help/reference?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can compute an uncertainty.  You'd be trying to divide by zero.
j/k but not really.  You can really only use this type of Rietveld under strictly controlled circumstances.  You would need multiple types of controls in place.  Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.
Oh, this was posted years ago.  How did it go?